# Who was Déū Singh Baru, final raja of Nuwakot, Kakani?

Tags: royalty

A [stone inscription](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9JucCIzSLT0&t=358s) was recently found in Nepal, specifically in the area of [Nuwakot, Kakani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuwakot_District).

The first part of the inscription's heading reads **देउ सिंह बरू**, which can be anglicized to Déū Singh Baru. The rest of the heading says that it's a 'clay rumba'.

It turns out that Déū Singh Baru was the king of Nuwakot up until 1775 BCE. I haven't seen any information about him in Nepali history books, nor does much information seem to be available online.

Here is a screenshot from the video (5:39) to show the plaque:

[image]

So, who was this king? Was he a *thakuri*, which is the name for Nepali kings used in Hinduism? (Most subcontinental surnames have some sort of meaning, but *baru* doesn't mean anything in Nepali, doesn't bring to mind any caste, and has no religious significance either.)

Answer (score 3):

Ok I'm updating my answer as of new thing I've found. Baaru is a title which full form is Baarula i.e wasp in English. This title seems to belong to kirant dynasty as this thakuri clan were also king of kirantis as stated in baleswar inscription of Krachalla Deva (Western Malla)

> So long as the possessor of the place where the lotus loves to exist
> of the auspicious Krachalla deva wanders on the earth, so long may the
> lotus-aboded of the chief of the Kirantis.

The Thakuri's of Nepali origin i.e simha and malla thakuri was obscure in Nepali history. But with this new palace remains found in Nuwakot, we can conclude that the singh thakuris root was Baaru/Baarula Rumba. Rumba here is family name who is also called [thari lama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lama_clan_(Tamang)).

Dew Simha Baarula was the final simha thakuri of Nuwakot kingdom before annexed by Ratna Malla in kantipur kingdom.
Malla Thakuri and Singh Thakuri were two brothers of same clan. Malla Thakuri were also called Aringal and Simha Thakuri were also called Baaru/Baarula. Their are two brothers in Rumba clan one is Baaru/Baarula(wasp) and another is Aringal(hornet), Baaru Rumba is Singh/Simha and Aringal Rumba is Malla. Conclusive.

Malla thakuri of Nepal mandala and Malla thakuri of Khas kingdome belong to same clan as both shares same optional royal title Aringal after Malla and both share same clan deity; Avaloketeswara that of western Malla thakuri and Machindranath (Hindu name for Avaloketeswara) that of Nepal mandala Malla thakuri.

The western Mallas were vajrayan Buddhist Mallas and that of Nepal valley were shaivat Hindu Mallas. As the baleswar inscription of krachalla states him belonging to Buddhist jina family:

> He was the devote saugata (Buddhist) and shone like the sun in the
> lotus of the Jini-kula.

Among the five [Jini-kula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Tath%C4%81gatas) western malla belonged to Padma (Lotus) kula of which family deity is Avalokiteswara.